# Running Selenium Suites on a Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Does anyone know how to run a selenium test suite from a selenium grid.

I know you can do it programatically with a single test, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it with a full test suite.

Something like java -jar selenium-server.jar -host  -htmlSuite .

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) will help you a lot. It demonstrates how to set up a hub and nodes which connect to it registering their 'configurations' (what browsers/'capabilities' they have). And the last piece of the jigsaw which is having code programmatically connect to the hub and run tests on it (the hub will forward stuff to a relevant node so the tests get performed there).

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I know there is a way to launch tests on the grid programatically. I am looking for a way to launch a full suite on a grid that contains several tests.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Selenium Grid is a facility for Selenium RC users to run their tests across a variety of machines with fine-grained configurations (e.g., a particular version of a browser).  As far as I know, there's no ability to specify that in the htmlSuite.  If there were, you might be able to make it work.  But running just a suite like this is not supported and likely never will be because that's not what it was designed for.

Comment: I agree with Nirvdrum. Selenium grid is not intended to be a Test Runner; it was rather designed for browser compatibility testing

Comment: I probably should add that I'm the maintainer for the Selenium Grid project, so my response is "official."  Having said that, it is open source so if you can get it working, have at it.